# Zend_Soap_Client request is creating the specified parameters but is not setting the values in the resulting XML that is sent

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I have a Zend_Soap_Client object, and I'm trying to call a method on it:

```
$soapClient = new Zend_SoapClient('my_wsdl');

$params = array(
   'Login'   => 'username',
   'Message' => 'hello'
);

$soapClient->GetSoapRequest($params);

echo $soapClient->getLastRequest();
```

I would expect to see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope ...>
 <env:Body>
  <ns1:GetSoapRequest>
   <ns1:Message>hello</ns1:Message>
   <ns1:Login>username</ns1:Login>
  </ns1:GetSoapRequest>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But what I actually see is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope ...>
 <env:Body>
  <ns1:GetSoapRequest>
   <ns1:Message/>
   <ns1:Login/>
  </ns1:GetSoapRequest>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

So it creates the correct fields but does not populate them with the content.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct way to pass parameters? Do you have a manual link somewhere?

Comment: I'd gone with that based on http://www.prodevtips.com/2009/06/08/zend-soap-client-example-talking-with-java-services/ though the docs at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html would suggest I should use:

    $soapClient->GetSoapRequest('username', 'hello');

Though if I do that the result is:


    <env:Envelope ...><br />
     <env:Body>  
      <ns1:GetSoapRequest/>  
      <param1>hello</param1>  
     </env:Body>  
    </env:Envelope>  


Notice how the params are outside of the GetSoapRequest, and the first one is skipped completely.

Comment: Sorry, formatting is lost in the comment - see http://pastebin.com/zCcXB7DB

Comment: which version of the Zend soap client are you working with? Maybe there was a change in the way parameters are parsed?

Answer (score 0):

Have sorted this now.  I needed to pass further structure in.  I'm guessing that the code I provided was valid, if the WSDL had specified it in that way.  For this though I needed something along the lines of:

```
$params = array(
   'Login'   => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'),
   'Message' => array('body' => 'hello')
);
```

Thanks for the help Pekka - sorry for the waste of time.